# How can I set the height of the window without worrying about the title bar?

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, nw.js

In my package.json, I'm using

```json
"window": {
    "resizable": false,
    "width": 640,
    "height": 480
  }
```

to set the height of the window to 480.

Because of the title bar, the window only shows about ~460 vertical pixels of the content.

I can compensate by raising the height to 500, but I would think that the title bar's height varies by operating system, so that's not a good solution if I care about consistency.

What can I do to make the window the exact height that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want to calculate the difference between the window's inner height (i.e `window.innerHeight`) and the overall height of the window (i.e `win.height`) and then add to it the desired height.

it'll look something like this:

```js
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var win = gui.Window.get();
// (Full window height - Document real height) + desired height
win.height = (win.height - window.innerHeight) + 480;
```

Comment: This works, but is there any way to do it in package.json instead of using JavaScript?